# How to change the title of an ad

Tags: android, admob

I can't find how to change the "title" (I don't know how it is called) of an ad using Admob. In the screenshot below (from Android Studio's emulator), what I call a title is "Test ad", at the top of the screen. I've searched on the Internet but I couldn't find anything related. I also checked Admob settings, but I didn't find anything.

[image: Ad screenshot, taken in Android Studio's emulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Test Ad" at the top will not appear when you ship your app in a production environment.

That is added because your device/emulator is marked as a testing device, therefore Admob indicates that to you with the "test ad" chip at the top. If you run the app with a device that's not marked as a "testing" device then you will see that the "test ad" does not appear.

More details: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads